# What does it mean when Pride mentions about Edward turning into a philosopher's stone to infiltrate him?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In episode 61, when the fight goes on between Edward and Pride, Kimblee interferes with the mind of Pride. Edward uses this moment to attack Pride by getting into his mind (or body maybe). However, as this occurs, the dialog of Pride to Edward is this:

> he turned himself into a philosopher's stone to infiltrate me?

What does this mean and how it is possible as Edward is not in possession of a philosopher's stone (not sure whether he can do it with a philosopher's stone)?

Comment: When Edward is injured after the fight with Kimbley before the mines earlier in the story, he turns himself into a philosopher's stone to seal his wound. Since humans are nothing but energy (philosophers stones consist of human souls), he uses alchemy to turn himself into energy to reach Pride's Soul. That would be my explanation

Comment: @Raildex in the episode that you mentioned, Edward didn't turn himself into a philosopher's stone, it was  mere a expression so that he could bear the pain.He used his medical alchemy to seal his wound.

Comment: `dimwittedanimal` provided the best response. When Darius and Heinkel hold Edward still (and remove the pipe in his chest), Edward notes "this'll take a few years off my life": he's aware he's performing medical alchemy and using his soul as a battery/exchange-for-parts to help him repair his body. Medical alchemy seems to violate the laws of thermodynamics less than other forms of alchemy (i.e. mass and souls obey equivalent exchange, but energy is free, except when repairing organs). Seems in human transmutation & medical alchemy, the whole really is greater than the sum of the parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remember that philosopher's stones are merely the souls of people.

I haven't watched the episode in a while, but I'm fairly certain Edward explains it as using part of his own soul/life force to generate a philosopher's stone.

Edit: found this on the [wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_61:_He_Who_Would_Swallow_God_(2009_series))

> Breaking free of his bonds, Edward takes hold of Pride's head and, turning himself once more into a single-souled Philosopher's Stone, forces his way into the Homunculus' psyche.

Answer (score 0):

Edward was one of five that were sacrificed to open the Gate to god. This could mean that they've gained more knowledge since they've sacrificed so many in Amestris to create a philosopher's stone for Father.

The first time he opened the Gate was during Human Transmutation for reviving his mother. Due to what he sacrificed; he gained the ability to perform alchemy without transmutation circles. When he claps his hands together, he forms a circle.

I believe he gained more knowledge/abilities towards alchemy for opening the Gate to God. Also when people have opened the Gate and use alchemy without transmutation circles, they do it without realizing they didn't need a circle until after they performed their alchemy.

This could explain Edward turning into a stone from the new knowledge he gained. Father could turn people into Philosopher's stones by just reaching out towards people, pulling their souls and procure it in his palm.